# Boot to tty2 on start

Tags: 12.04, boot, tty

On Ubuntu 12.04 I had a server with no GDM.  I want to boot to tty2 on start up.  What would I put into rc.local?

Note* I do not have grub

tty1:

```
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345] and (
    not-container or
    container CONTAINER = lxc or
    container CONTAINER = lxc-libvirt)
stop on runlevel [!2345}

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

tty2 is the same except on `RUNLEVEL [23]`

Comment: Why tty1 is not suitable? Which bootloader do you have? Do you mean autologin or just the login prompt?

Comment: I dont have a bootloader, it is an ARM device.  My tty1 logs into as root, so in rc.loacal I put 'su -l user' to log into a user but it just gives me a blank screen.  I don't want root logged in and I would like it to automatically switch to tty2

Comment: Can you post the content of `/etc/init/tty1.conf` and `tty2.conf`?

Comment: @CijcoSistems Added code to main post

Comment: I think you should get a login prompt on tty1 (instead of a root shell), please check you have _login_ installed: `dpkg -s login | grep Status`

Comment: @CijcoSistems returned `Stats: install ok installed`  As a side note it logs into ttymxc0, I am unable to access tty1 even tho I want to believe the are the same screen.  I also have been abley to find a ttymxc0.conf file

Comment: Does this file have different contents?

Comment: @CijcoSistems I am sorry, i meant to say I have not been able to find ttymxc0.  Is it possible to do a search for the file?

Comment: Sure, you can do a `find / -iname '*ttymxc0*'` and it will search the whole system for any file which name contains ttymxc0 (you can restrict the search specifying /etc or some other directory instead of /). Btw (forgive me for the question if it looks too obvious), have you tried switching terminals with Alt+F1, Alt+F2, ..., Alt+F7?

Comment: @CijcoSistems I have tried to switch terminals, It all works fine except I tty1 is replaced by ttymxc0 which is automatically logged in as root.

Comment: I've been looking around for some information about _ttymxc0_ and found https://community.freescale.com/mobile/mobile-access.jspa#jive-discussion?content=%2Fapi%2Fcore%2Fv2%2Fdiscussions%2F327455 Is that your question? I've found something about U-boot as bootloader. I don't know what is your configuration, but sometimes when the system is not fully "installed" (as we understand it nowadays) you may get dropped to a shell with full privileges. Not like an auto-login for root but as if the system was saying "ok, I'm done, that's how far I can go, now you're in command". May this be your case?